# include classes in header files in other header files

Tags: c++, header, include, forward-declaration

I have two classes Screen and Window_Mgr(C++ Primer 5th Edition Chapter 7).

1. Screen is a class that contains three **string::size_types** and a **string** as data members.
2. Window_Mgr is a class that contains an object **Screens** of type **vector<*Screen*>**.
3. It initializes the **vector<*Screen*>** with the values **(24,80,’ ‘)** with a constructor in Screen.
4. void **Window_Mgr::clear(vector::size_type i)** is a function that accesses the private members of string and clears them of all data.

I want to write this code in such a way that only Window_Mgr::clear is a friend of Screen.

The problems I am faced with are:

1. If I define Window_Mgr before Screen with an incomplete declaration I can’t initialize **Screens**.
2. If I define Screen before Window_Mgr with an incomplete declaration I can’t declare **Window_Mgr::clear** as a friend of **Screen**.

I tried including them with separate header files but that was a real mess.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Screen;

struct Window_Mgr{
public:
    //    using Screen_Index = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    typedef std::vector<Screen>::size_type Screen_Index;

    void clear(Screen_Index i);

    Window_Mgr() = default;

private:
    std::vector<Screen> Screens;
};



struct Screen{

    typedef std::string::size_type pos;

    friend void Window_Mgr::clear(Screen_Index i);

    Screen() = default;
    Screen(pos h, pos w, char s): height(h), width(w), contents(h*w,s){};

    char get() const { return contents[cursor];}
    char get(pos ht, pos width)const;
    Screen &move(pos r, pos c);
    Screen &set(char);
    Screen &set(pos, pos, char);
    Screen & display(std::ostream &);
    const Screen & display (std::ostream &) const;

    pos size() const;


private:
    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;
    const Screen do_display (std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os << contents;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating encapsulation by having `Screen` call `Window_Mgr`.

The `Window_Mgr` is a container of `Screen`s.  The `Window_Mgr` should call the `clear` method of a screen.

```
struct Screen
{
  void clear()
  {
     //...
  }
};


struct Window_Mgr
{
  std::vector<Screen> Screen_Container;
  void clear_screen(unsigned int screen_index)
  {
    Screen_Container[screen_index].clear();
  }
};
```

Due to simplicity, I have not placed in checks for index ranges.

**Edit 1:  Friendship.**
There is no need for friendship here.  The `Window_Mgr` can only access what the `Screen` class has defined in its interface.

Also, the `Screen` class should have no knowledge of whether it is in a container or not; that concept belongs to the `Window_Mgr` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't get these portions:
 `You are violating encapsulation by having Screen call Window_Mgr.`
 If you mean this line `friend void Window_Mgr::clear(Screen_Index i);` I am calling a member function of Window_Mgr.. Is that not allowed?

 `Also, the Screen class should have no knowledge of whether it is in a container or not; that concept belongs to the Window_Mgr class`
 How does the class know if it is a container?

Comment: Think, why does the `Screen` need to call `Window_Mgr`?  This means that the `Screen` object knows about its container.  Anything `Screen` related belongs to `Screen` not `Window_Manager`.

Comment: The idea is pretty vague in my head but as far as i understand...

`Window_Mgr::Screens` is a container of `Screen` and in clear func I am calling screen to clear members of `Window_Mgr::Screens`and not calling screen to clear its own members through its own function which makes it less modular? O_O' *Please have patience I might be dumb as... But I would like to understand this...

Comment: The Window_Mgr should iterate through the vector or screens, calling the `clear` method for each screen.  If the Window_Mgr needs to clear its members, it should do that in its own methods.  Screen should not call any functions in Window_Mgr.

Answer (score 2):

consider using classes instead and your forward declaration is for a class, where you create screen as a struct. This might be causing some of your issues. and instead of using a friend how about two separate clear functions one for Window_mgr that calls a different clear function in Screen.

your window_mgr clear would be something like

```
void Window_Mgr::clear(int i)
{
    Screens.at(i).clear();
}
```

and your Screen clear would be something like

```
void Screen::clear()
{
    //whatever you want to do to private variables here
}
```

And as one of my professors beat into our heads "Friends of classes are not friends of programmers"

Comment: Can you quote a language standard where `public` and `private` have "no meaning for structs"?  The only difference, in C++, between `struct` and `class` is the default accessibility.  For `struct`, the default accessibility is `public`, and for `class` it is `private`.

Comment: I was mistaken that is in c... sometimes i get confused. Thanks for pointing out my error i have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that "Friends of classes are not friends of programmers" in mind! :D